# Datagridview remove duplicate rows

Tags: c#, datagridview

i need your help with deleting duplicates from datagrid. I made this,

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow viewrow1 in this.dataGridView1.Rows) 
        {

            DataRowView row1 = viewrow1.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
            if(row1 != null){
                foreach (DataGridViewRow viewRow2 in this.dataGridView2.Rows)
                {
                    DataRowView row2 = viewRow2.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
                    if (row2 != null && row1.Row["test"].Equals(row2.Row["test"]))
                    {
                        row2.Row.Delete();

                    }

                } 
            }

        }
```

it works, but wont delete 1 row.

Thx for your help.

Comment: Do you want to delete row1 as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow viewrow1 in this.dataGridView1.Rows) 
    {

        DataRowView row1 = viewrow1.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
        if(row1 != null){
            foreach (DataGridViewRow viewRow2 in this.dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                DataRowView row2 = viewRow2.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
                if (row2 != null && row1.Row["test"].Equals(row2.Row["test"]))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row2);

                }

            } 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.Remove(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: Don't remove items from collection as you're iterating over it;

Comment: i don't understand. the point is , i need to delete duplicate tables if data in datagridview1 is same as in datagridview2 then delete that rows.